# What do the green boxes mean?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, linked-questions, related-questions

Some posts have their vote count highlighted green, while others do not. What does this mean? Does it just mean that that post has a high amount of upvotes? Does it mean the post does not have a single downvote? A specific upvote to downvote ratio? A combination of these? Sorry if this is already posted somewhere; I couldn't find it...
[image]

Comment: It simply means a Question has an Accepted Answer.

Comment: Oh...that was pretty stupid of me. Thanks

Comment: This seems rather similar to this older post: [What is the meaning of green in number of answers in a question list?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/25005/what-do-the-green-boxes-mean). Although I do not see any post where *vote count* is green, for questions with accepted answers *number of answers* has green background. So either you mean something else or we are using different ways to view the site and we get different results.

Comment: @MartinSleziak The number always corresponds to the number of votes and not the number of answers...

Comment: BTW I have posted by mistake wrong link in my previous comment. But in my answer (or clarification attempt) below I have already included the correct link to: [What is the meaning of green in number of answers in a question list?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23099/what-is-the-meaning-of-green-in-number-of-answers-in-a-question-list)

Comment: I agree with Martin. This question is poorly phrased, especially since the question repeats the emphasis on the score, as opposed to the number of answers.

Comment: Added a screenshot.

Comment: @hardmath Now that the question has been clarified, I think that you could expand your comment to an answer. (What I posted below is closer to an expanded comment or request to clarification rather than to actual answer.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak:  Your work cleared the way for the Question to be clarified to what must be almost everyone's satisfaction.  I encourage you to tweak your existing answer as needed and undelete (I already upvoted it).

Answer (score 3):

This question relates to two places: related questions to the right of a post on either the meta site or the main site, and question and answer lists in one's profile. These lists display the score given by votes in a grey or light green box. The box is light green when there has been an accepted answer, and the box is grey when there is no accepted answer.

On the home page, only the answers count box becomes green if there has been an accepted answer.